# No keyboard after suspend, even after hard reset

Tags: keyboard, suspend, live-cd

While I was using a Ubuntu 9.1 live CD, I put the computer (Toshiba Satellite C655) into standby. After I resumed, the keyboard stopped functioning, though the mouse (USB) still worked.

I decided to turn off the computer, but after Ubuntu shuts down, it asks you to press "enter" to actually turn the machine off. The keyboard was still dead, so I all I could do was use the on/off switch to power down the computer.

Now, when I try to boot the computer, nothing happens. Before this problem, I would see a menu asking me to select an OS (I had Windows 7 and Windows XP installed). I cannot use any emergency measures because I need to press F12 to boot from a CD, and the keyboard is *still* not working.

I tried removing the HD to force a boot from the CD, but it didn't work. I also tried to plug in a USB keyboard, which failed as well. Right now, I have no idea how to fix this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If the keyboard isn't working in your BIOS menu, unfortunately it is very, very likely a hardware issue.  You can try to use a USB keyboard, or you may need to get yours fixed (or it may have become unplugged somehow, although that's quite unlikely)